# Roots of irreducible polynomials in a finite field

Tags: finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

If $f$ and $g$ are irreducible polynomials over a finite field $\mathbb F_q$, both of degree $d$, then they both split in $\mathbb F_{q^d}$. One way to represent $\mathbb F_{q^d}$ is to adjoin a root $\alpha$ of $f$. As a basis are the elements $1,\alpha,\ldots,\alpha^{d-1}$. My question is, what are the coordinates of the roots of $g$ with respect to this basis?

Comment: I don't think this can be answered in general. I think one has to know what $\;g\;$ is.

Comment: One has to know what *both* $f$ and $g$ are to answer this. Choice of $f$ defines the basis. Choice of $g$ tells us what to look for. Then there is, of course, the task of actually finding the roots of $g$.